# Postman - Is It Possible To Have URL NOT Required

Tags: request, postman, data-manipulation

I'm new to postman and I was wondering something. I have some tests in a collection that test for 200's from an array and that's fine. I need to extract some data from the response and add some extra data to URLs returned from the API im hitting (That's fine)

My question is, is it possible to have a request in a collection that doesn't try to hit some URL. Basically I need a request in a collection that just does some data manipulation and passes that new data onto the next request for further 200's testing, but as it stands I need to enter a value for the URL in order for the request to run (I don't want a request for this part I just want a.......thing to do....something that isn't actually a request).

Currently I'm doing this on a GET request and just hitting google.com, but i'd like this to be neater and not have to do that.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can send it on localhost instead

Comment: yes but that's my point. I always have to request from somewhere. If I point it at localhost, I have to have something running on local host, otherwise it fails, no?

Answer (score 0):

This is also a feature that I have been searching for, and as far as I can tell, is still not present in Postman.

In my example, I am using the Collection Runner, taking an input data file, to run a sequence multiple times.  The APIs being called all use bearer authentication, and I only need to request the bearer token once, not on every iteration.

The first Request in a sequence is always executed at the start of every iteration, so if I can make that some kind of dummy call, then I can decide in the Test code if I want to request a bearer token or skip and move the actual API call I need to make.

Like the OP, the only way I can think to do this is to call some random, small, site on the public internet.

I have raised a Feature Request to Postman.  I wonder if they will take it up.
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/11713

Comment: If you only need the bearer token call once, you can use variables in a POSTMAN Environment, you call the GetBearerToken call once, then share that token across other calls.